# ¿Como asignar una imagen por defecto a una cuenta de usuario en GO?

Tags: login, go

Estoy creando un login de usuario, pero quiero hacer que al momento que me genere el usuario creado, automáticamente se le asigne una imagen de usuario, como una imagen base, con esto me refiero a por ejemplo `facebook`, que al momento que creas una cuenta, aparece un pictograma de hombre o mujer como imagen de perfil, quiero hacer algo similar en mi login, alguien podría orientarme de como hacerlo? aquí el código que me genera al usuario.

```
token, _ = APP.Jwt.GenerateToken(jwt.MapClaims{
    "iat": APP.Jwt.GenerateIAT(),
    "exp": APP.Jwt.GenerateEXP(),
    "iss": APP.Jwt.GenerateISS(),
    "aud": APP.Jwt.GenerateAUD(),
    "jti": APP.Jwt.GenerateJTI(),
    "sub": APP.Jwt.GenerateSUB(),

    "id":        u.ID.Hex(),
    "email":     u.Email,
    "phone":     u.Phonenumber,
    "username":  u.Username,
    "bio":       u.Biography,
    "age":       u.Age,
    "nickname":  u.Nickname,
    "createdAt": u.CreatedAt,
})
```

Cabe destacar que los pictograma que usare son locales.

Comment: Eso es inseguro, en un login no debes darle información a un hacker, Debes dar mensajes del tipo "Usuario y/o contraseña incorrecto" de tal manera que no das información si el usuario esta mal o si es la contraseña. Si agregas un avatar a un login una vez que el usuario es correcto, ya le das información a los hackers de que ya encontraron un usuario y solo deben dar con la contraseña. Lo que quieres hacer es valido si ya te has logueado pero es inseguro si lo haces desde la ventana de login.

Comment: exacto, eso es lo que busco, colocar una imagen predefinida, (pictograma hombre / mujer según corresponda ) una vez el usuario se este creado, pero hacerlo de forma local.

Comment: Cuando creas el usuario, en la base de datos en el campo de imagen de perfil le podrias colocar un valor por default, ejem => "default_avatar.jpg" que haga referencia a una imagen default en los assets de imagen; así cuando hagas el login te regrese la consulta la imagen default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creas tu función `Nuevo` dentro del paquete `Usuario` recibiendo como parámetros los campos que pides al crear el usuario. Tomando de ejemplo que tus campos son: "nombre" y "contraseña".

```
package usuario

const imagenDefault string = "<Path a tu imagen>"

//Usuario estructura con la informacion de Usuario
type Usuario struct {
    Nombre     string
    Contrasena string
    Imagen     string
}

//Nuevo retorna el apuntador del objeto de un nuevo usuario
func Nuevo(nombre, contrasena string) *Usuario {
    var nuevoUsuario = &Usuario{
        Nombre:     nombre,
        Contrasena: contrasena,
        Imagen:     imagenDefault,
    }

    return nuevoUsuario
}
```

Y para mandarlo llamar seria algo asi:

```
package main

func main(){
    var adminUser = usuario.Nuevo("admin", "admin")
}
```

Si quieres usar el package [image](https://golang.org/pkg/image/) de Go quedaria mejor para que no tengas que depender del path directo de tu imagen.

> Package image implements a basic 2-D image library.
>
> The fundamental interface is called Image. An Image contains colors, which are described in the image/color package.

Así puedes leer la imagen y guardar el arreglo de bytes correspondiente a tu imagen, aunque eso depende más de las necesidades y recursos que tengas.